# NestList: How to have a parameter that is changing as a function of nest index, n?

Tags: iteration

I have a NestList construction

```
NestList[STEP[#] &, m0, NT]
```

where a function is being called repeatedly that acts on a list and returns a list, for details, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/201701/speeding-up-an-intrinsically-sequential-operation).

Let NT in the NestList denote a discrete time, and let's say I'd like to have a parameter that is passed to the STEP function *as a function of discrete time*.

In other words, I'd like to pass a parameter temperature that's like:

```
temperature = Table[ii/NT,{ii,1,NT}]
```

to my STEP function through NestList.

I am sure there is an easy way to do this, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Try `FoldList[STEP[#, #2] &, m0, Table[ii/NT, {ii, 1, NT}] ]`?

Comment: This worked like a charm ... Thank you !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`FoldList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldList.html):

```
FoldList[STEP[#, #2] &, m0, Table[ii/NT, {ii, 1, NT}] ]
```